# How to create Desktop-like Window in HTML and CSS (and/or JS/JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make page as standard desktop window - titlebar, menubar, toolbar on top. statusbar fixed on bottom. And finally - main content with scrollbar on center. Everything inside body tag (or some div.container tag), but body tag should has got always 100% of workspace. no more and no less.

titlebar, menubar and statusbar have got const heights, but **content should be relative to browser window size.**

Is this possible to do this without using JS?

I tried to do this with different combinations of css properties - height, max-height, position, display, overflow, but then main content expands the body above of 100% of workspace (so scrollbar appears related to body tag, instead of related to main content).

How to fix this?

---

Edit: why you minusing me? This is real problem without simple solution.

---

Edit 2:

```
(...)
<body class="window-without-scrollbar-and-100%-of-browser-window-size">
    <div class="titlebar-const-height"></div>
    <div class="menubar-const-height"></div>
    <div class="main-content-with-scrollbar-and-with-size-relative-to-browser-window">
        <?php loremIpsumGenerator('very long'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="statusbar-fixed-position-and-const-height"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: And what was your own finding among all the solutions you can google for?

Comment: https://www.google.pl/search?q=html+desktop+window - nothing special

Comment: We can't know how to fix your code without seeing it.

Comment: You would get a much better reception to this type of question if you include a minimal demonstration of the problem, including 1) The markup + CSS you have, and 2) an explanation of the problems you have with how this is displaying. People can then resolve your specific problem rather than having to basically write an entire implementation for you.

Comment: You would not to see spaghetti as step-by-step experimental trials of solving this problem, believe me.

Comment: _"You would not to see spaghetti as step-by-step experimental trials of solving this problem, believe me."_ - are you high? What does that even mean? Anyhow, you are probably looking for `width: calc()` which allows you to do something like `width: calc(100% - 40px)` (where 40px would be your close button width, for example). That way the height can be fixed but the width variable.

Comment: I just want to implement simple template of this layout in HTML - http://www.editcorp.com/personal/lars_appel/howto/g1.gif

Comment: Why wont you let us know what you've tried ?

Comment: @somethinghere: "calc()" - O.o so CSS can counts? Damn, did I overslept something? I thought that it could be possible only with css rendered by php or Less or Sass. I should to try this.

Comment: You could just create several divs, use float to put the three buttons to the right, and the title and icon to the left. It can pretty much be done to look like a window in very simple HTML and CSS. making it appear as a movable dialogue box, is a bit of a different story. Have you looked at maybe using jQuery Dialog?

Comment: @Pogrindis: Because I have got not history of commits of this problem. And I am now here: http://www.simplesignshop.com/images/150/cliff_sign_end_of_road.jpg

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for (as I mentioned in the comments) is the `calc()` function in CSS. `calc()` allows you to let CSS do some of the hard work for you, and I use it to recalculate percentage sized widths into pixel sized ones for browsers that support it. For backwards compatibility with older browsers, I'd suggest trying the following snippet.

```css
#windowBar {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 40px;
}

#windowBar .titlebar {
    width: 80%;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    background: #ececec;
}

#windowBar .closebutton {
    width: 20%;
    width: calc(40px);
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
    <div id="windowBar">
        <div class="titlebar">My Window Title</div>
        <div class="closebutton">Close</div>
    </div>
```

After this its a matter of styling, position (aka use fixed and creating your own scrollable area *between the bars* (using something like `height: calc(100% - 40px);`)) and so on. This is a very simple problem actually.

Comment: Are you sure about 'width' not 'height'?

Comment: @user3383675 Calc works for both, I was just giving an example. This is how I would do it but I haven't gone deep enough in there to see any issues crop up with the height thing. Though I don't think you'd need calc for height apart from your content area, which would not have a fixed height (all the UI bars would have a fixed height, but not width, only the content would stretch I assume.).

Comment: It should be vertical, not horizontal

Comment: @123qwe I have problems understanding what exactly you are looking for or asking, even when you provide a screenshot. Please read the answer thoroughly and give it a try, since the vertical space issue works exactly the same as the horizontal space on (remember that you html and body need a height of 100% for a calc like that to work properly). And at the end of my answer you will find `height: calc(100% - 40px);`. That should do the trick.